# Connect to BLE peripheral on Windows 10

Tags: windows, bluetooth

I try to connect to BLE peripheral. First, I watch for advertisements:

```cs
watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher { ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active };
watcher.Received += WatcherOnReceived;
watcher.Start();
```

and in the WatcherOnReceived callback I try to create BluetoothLEDevice

```cs
public async void WatcherOnReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs btAdv)
{
    BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAdv.BluetoothAddress);
}
```

However, I always get bleDevice == null in WatcherOnReceived callback. Why and how to fix it? What is the proper way of creating BLE device in UWP application? I then need to connect to that device, discover its GATT services and characteristics, enable notifications on some of them and read/write some of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is simple - do not use BLE on Windows 10. The API doesn't work or behaves randomly and is totally undocumented. I like everyone talking about IoT being next industrial revolution and Microsoft not having working BLE API after 6 year BLE exists.

Comment: Haha I certainly agree that everything is random and kind of undocumented. The most annoying thing is that they don't have one single compact and complete BLE API but rather try to integrate it with other Windows Devices (in device manager) and expose each GATT service as a device + the need to use like 5 different APIs to get everything you want.

Comment: Is situation still the same (two years later)?

Comment: The same question. Is situation still the same (3 years later)?

Comment: The API was improved significantly with the Creators Update from March 2017. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/bluetooth-low-energy-overview

Answer (score 1):

See example 8 and 9 in https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing if you want to be able to connect to previously non-paired BLE devices, i.e. use a DeviceWatcher with a Bluetooth LE selector.

Otherwise you need to first pair it in the system's bluetooth pairing settings before you will be able to retrieve a BluetoothLEDevice from FromBluetoothAddressAsync.

Comment: Thanks. I paired my BLE device in scenario 9 of that samples. Now, IsPaired flag shows true on that device.But I still get bleDevice == null in my app. Once I got exception 0x80070490 on .FromBluetoothAddressAsync call.

Comment: It looks like there are no filters on the advertisement watcher- are you sure that the device you are trying to connect to is the BLE device you are interested in? Some BLE devices are not connectable where you can only receive advertisements from them.

Comment: So Bluetooth connection is initiated by BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAdv.BluetoothAddress); ? And yes, I'm sure this is the device I want to connect to, as it is the only BLE device in my proximity.

Answer (score 0):

You can check device information in `WatcherOnReceived()` to ensure that the device is what you want to connect with. Do it like this:

```cs
public async void WatcherOnReceived(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs btAdv)
{
    if (btAdv.Advertisement.LocalName == "SensorTag")
    {
        BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(btAdv.BluetoothAddress);
    }    
}
```

Use your own BLE device name instead of "SensorTag".

Note: You need pair your BLE device beforehand(either programatically like DeviceEnumerationAndPairing sample or PC's setting app as shown in the following image.).[image]

Comment: I can see, that my BLE device is never displayed in Settings->Devices->Bluetooth, even when PC is searching for devices. But I can see the device when I run Windows platform samples, scenario 8 or 9. The device is paired. I can also see the device in WatcherOnReceived callback. But FromBluetoothAddressAsync always return null for the device.

Comment: @MartinDusek Add the following code before `UpdatePairingButtons();`  in `PairButton_Click()` of `Scenario8_PairDevice`.     `if(dpr.Status == DevicePairingResultStatus.Paired)
            {
                BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Id);
            }` Then run Scenario8, pair selected device and check connection status. Note:Connect with device need some time. If you immediately check `bleDevice ` after pairing it maybe `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Still bleDevice evaluates to null after FromIdAsync() call. However I noticed that the scenario 8 (without or even with your modification) probably somehow connects to my BLE device after I click on pair button because my BLE device then stops advertising. It restarts advertising when I click unpair button. Does it mean the connection/disconnection to the device is performed by the pairing/unpairing procedure? Is there any documentation for that behaviour? BLE on Windows seems to me to be a real magic...

Comment: @MartinDusek You can check if the connection is valid or not by discovering its GATT services and characteristics. Sample is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-scenarios).

Comment: OK. I created thermometer BLE device. I paired it. I then used a code snippet from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-scenarios) to get all thermometer services, but I get no thermometer service.

Comment: Today, some magic happened, BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync returns valid objects for unpaired BLE devices (I haven't modified a single word in the code). But it still returns null for paired device (my newly created thermometer). I'm becoming little frustrated... BLE behaviour on Windows is obviously randomized, I have no explanation for that. Is there anyone who was able to connect to BLE device on Windows? Or is there something wrong with my Windows 10 computer?

Comment: Why BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync returns null with no error message or so?

Comment: Documentation on [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.frombluetoothaddressasync) states that FromBluetoothAddressAsync "returns the BluetoothDevice object with the given BluetoothAddress or null if the address does not resolve to a valid device." Why is the BluetoothAddress  delivered to me via BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs invalid for some devices?

Comment: @MartinDusek Which peripheral are you trying to connect to?

Comment: It is our custom device with custom GATT services (my company uses this device for a while, we can communicate with it on Android and Qt/Windows without any issue). I also tried to connect to standard BLE thermometer.