# Windows BLuetooth LE require pairing before connection?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

It seems from other posts (all quite old) that Windows 10 BLE requires (external) pairing before one can work with the device.

Is this still true?
Can I connect to a device without pairing and control the pairing myself (if needed)

If Windows requires pairing to work with a device, that is bad because many BLE devices do not support pairing.

My use case is remote patient monitoring, where a patient performs measurements with personal health medical devices. The patient needs to do as little as possible. On the Android I do the following and would like to do the same in Windows:

1. Scan in the background for BTLE devices my app can work with
   (filtering on UUIDs; all devices that support the standard health
   thermometer, pulse ox, BP, Glucose, weigh scale, etc.).
2. When a supported device is discovered, a popup appears and all user
   has to do is select connect or no.
3. If the device needs pairing, it will be done automatically, either
       because the device sends a security request OR responds with an
       insufficient authentication error when I try to read/write/enable.
4. If confirmation or passkey is needed, a second popup will occur.
       This is the most difficult part for the user.
5. If pairing is not needed, it will never happen. I will never try to
       pair with a device that does not support it.
6. If paired and bonded, the device is added to a list of known devices
       and when discovered, connection happens automatically with no user
       intervention.
7. If unpairable, the device is still added to a list of known devices
       and when discovered, connection happens automatically with no user
       intervention. Of course I have to go through service discovery
       again.

That is what I would like to emulate on Windows. The user shall need to know *nothing* about the device except how to use it and, unfortunately, make it pairable and/or connectable which is not standard and a big hurdle. The user should also have as little engagement as possible with the app. The minimum is a one time choice to connect (or not) and a pairing dialog (if needed).

This works great on Android (barring Android's unstable BTLE).

Comment: Maybe you have seen it too but this might be the answer for your question: [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38704180/11385066)

Comment: It depends on Windows 10 build. You can find more information about pairing requirements by this link: https://www.btframework.com/ble.htm

Comment: @MCP2019 The down side of what I see in that post (which I did look at) was the use of the device watcher which requires that one pick a device ahead of time. That is a horrible scenario. Pairing and discovery is complicated for users, especially elderly users in my scenario for remote patient monitoring. I will add some more to the post to explain

Comment: @MikePetrichenko this framework looks like a third party library and not the built in Windows API. We already have such third party libraries and do not want to continue use those. They get out of date and are expensive and require special driver installations. We are only interested in the Windows APIs.

Comment: I gave a link to the article that describes pairing requirements of Windows 10 for BLE device. This does not depend on library usage and valid for native Windows WinRT BLE API.

Comment: Here is what the artcile says: If you run Windows 10 1609 and above and your Bluetooth LE device is paired you may face issue with receiving OnDisconnect event. Unapir device before connect.
Note for Windows 10 1703 and above
Windows 10 1703 and above and your Bluetooth LE device is paired you may face issue with reading device services, characteristics and other properties. Unpair device before connect.
Windows 10 1803 and above
Windows 10 1803 and above and your Bluetooth LE devuce is paired you may get randomly device disconnection. Unpair device before connect.

Comment: Windows 10 before 1609 and Windows 8 requires pairing with device using Windows UI. BLE is not supported on any Windows before Win 8. On Win 8 only classic GATT API is available.

Answer (score 1):

No.Pairing is not even recommended, unless for security or if you want to combine your connections with Classic Bluetooth to get extra functionality.

With Bluetooth LE it quite common to connect and communicate without pairing.
You can even send a small amount of user definable data to any listening devices without any connection at all via advertisement packets. However, if you connect without pairing, then the connection is not secure, because there are no link security keys that may be used to encrypt the connection.

Bonding and pairing in BLE often happen at the same time, but they are technically different. Pairing is part of the link encryption process, which may happen without bonding. Bonding is the long-term storage of encryption info (particularly keys) so that the devices “know” each other and can easily reconnect in an encrypted way. If you enable bondable mode, you are allowing this long-term storage to occur. Without bondable mode, it is still possible to temporarily pair to form an encrypted connection.

Here is a link to a site where it's explained rather good. It is about some specific BLE modules, but it's great information:
https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2015/08/06/_reference_bonding-lnVL

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer 'not recommended'. As a client app, I need to comply with the peer. If the peer requires pairing, I must pair. If it requires MITM, I will need to allow entry of a passkey. If it doesn't require pairing, then I won't try to pair and risk disconnection..

Comment: I will update my answer with some more information and a link to where it is explained.

Comment: I understand how BLE works. I have helped develop some of the BLE SIG health device profiles and have developed BLE health device centrals and peripherals on embedded and Android platforms. My interest is specifically health devices (which in the remote patient monitoring scenario) shall pair and bond, but in practice, many don't (but they still transfer data through connections and not broadcasting ... that's out of scope for this application). Nevertheless, as I added in the post above, I am intending the central to be as generic and as user-friendly as possible as we have done on Android.

Comment: You should also add that in the BLE world bonding also means saving all information such that a reconnect does not need to do service discovery and enabling. This allows very power efficient transfer of data. Reconnect, encrypt, send data, done. A big helper to keep the 'low' in bluetooth low energy.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/woodemi/quick_blue/issues/78#issuecomment-1078877700

> In-app Bluetooth LE discovering available with BlueSoleil Bluetooth drivers and with BLED112 Bluetooth dongle on any Windows platform. With Microsoft Bluetooth drivers:
>
> - On Windows 8 you must discovr and pair with Bluetooth LE device through Windows UI. After device paired you can discover it using in-app discovering methods.
> - On Windows 10 1607 and below you also have to pair with Bluetooth LE device through Windows UI. After device paired you can discover it using in-app discovering methods.
> - On Windows 10 1703 and above you do not need to pair with your device manually. You can discover nearby Bluetooth LE device using in-app discovering.